# How to Make Script Flexible when New Item is Loaded in SharePoint Folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010, rest, spservices

I am seeking help with my JavaScript script to make it expandable when a new item (video) is added to my SharePoint folder.  I created a counter that counts each time the video button is selected and displays the new count inside a div.  The script works as expected but I like to expand its capability to automatically adjust when a new video is added into the SharePoint video folder.  The video is dynamically added to an HTML page when dropped into the folder.  However, when I add a new video its loads into the zero-index position and move the others video down one; making the previous video in the zero-index position to the one position and so on.  Can someone view my script and see; if possible, how I can make my current script adjust accordingly when the new video is loaded?  I like to make it where I do not have to go back into script and renumber everything by hand when a new video is added.   I hope this question make sense.

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#column5", function() {

    videoHits();

    getFilesFromFolder("/sites/dcsa/ep/epMainFiles/BI/video").done(function(data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(i, item) {

            var spDate = new Date(item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0]) //example: '2015-10-30T05:00:00Z'
            var newTillDate = new Date();
            spDate.setDate(spDate.getDate() + 2);

            if (spDate <= newTillDate) {

                jQuery("#hiddenWrapper").fadeIn();

                $("#column1 ol").append('<li style="width:30%; height: auto; position: relative; left: 5%; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; float: left;" data-event-date="' + item.TimeCreated.split("T")[0] + '"><div class="btnImg" id="growPlayPauseBtn' + i + '"  style="width: 285px; height: 225px; position: absolute; top: 20px; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; padding: 10px; color: white; background-color: rgba(43, 92, 171, .35); display: block;">Play Video</div><video width="100%" height="auto" controls onended="videoEnded1()" id="videoClip' + i + '"><source src="' + item.ServerRelativeUrl + '" type="audio/mpeg" >' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + " - " + '<span style="color: red;">' + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0] + '</span>' + '</video><span  style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;  float: left; clear: both;" "' + item.TimeCreated.split("T")[0] + '">' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + " - " + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0] + '</span></br><div class="vidViews" id="vidHit' + i + '">Views: <span></span></div></li>');


                $("#column1 h3").html("Videos");

            } else {

                jQuery("#hiddenWrapper").fadeIn();

                $("#column1 ol").append('<li style="width:30%; height: auto; position: relative; left: 5%; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; float: left;" data-event-date="' + item.TimeCreated.split("T")[0] + '"><div class="btnImg" id="growPlayPauseBtn' + i + '"  style="width: 285px; height: 225px; position: absolute; top: 20px; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; padding: 10px; color: white; background-color: rgba(43, 92, 171, .35); display: block;">Play Video</div><video width="100%" height="auto" controls onended="videoEnded1()" id="videoClip' + i + '"><source src="' + item.ServerRelativeUrl + '" type="audio/mpeg" >' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + " - " + '<span style="color: red;">' + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0] + '</span>' + '</video><span  style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;  float: left; clear: both;" "' + item.TimeCreated.split("T")[0] + '">' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + " - " + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0] + '</span></br><div class="vidViews" id="vidHit' + i + '">Views: <span></span></div></li>');


                $("#column1 h3").html('<img class="newArrow" style="width: 60px; position: relative; right: 5px; top: 0px;"src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Test Page/icons/arrow-with_new2.gif" alt="logo">Videos');

            }
        });
    });

});




///Read hits from growVideoHits List

function videoHits() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var chartData = getListData("growVideoHits"); //vidHit
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
            data.push({
                "label": chartData[i].Title
            });
        }
        initChart(data);

    });

    function initChart(chartData) {

        //console.log(chartData);

        //Filter List Column for Specific Column Item
        var view0 = chartData.filter(function(d) {
            if (d["label"] == "Test Video") {
                return d;
            }
        })

        var view1 = chartData.filter(function(d) {
            if (d["label"] == "GROW HHM Guest Speaker") {
                return d;
            }
        })

        var view2 = chartData.filter(function(d) {
            if (d["label"] == "GROW Meeting 26 Aug 2020") {
                return d;
            }
        })


        var pageCount0 = view0.length;
        var pageCount1 = view1.length;
        var pageCount2 = view2.length;

        d3.select('#vidHit0 span').html(pageCount0);
        d3.select('#vidHit1 span').html(pageCount1);
        d3.select('#vidHit2 span').html(pageCount2);


    } //End of D3 function For Column Chart 


    function getListData(listName) {
        var results;
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=Title";
        $.ajax({
            url: requestUri,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                results = data.d.results;
            },
            error: function() {
                //alert("Failed to get details");                
            }
        });
        return results;
    }
}

////Play Buttons
jQuery(document).on("click", '[id^=growPlayPauseBtn]', function(e) {
    growBtn_Event(e);
});


function growBtn_Event(e) {

    if ($(e.target).attr("id") == 'growPlayPauseBtn0') {
        //alert('0');
        var title = "Test Video";
        AddListItem(title);
        videoClip0.play();
        jQuery("#growPlayPauseBtn0").html("Pause");
        jQuery("#growPlayPauseBtn0").fadeOut();
    }

    if ($(e.target).attr("id") == 'growPlayPauseBtn1') {
        //alert('1');
        var title = "GROW HHM Guest Speaker";
        AddListItem(title);
        videoClip1.play();
        jQuery("#growPlayPauseBtn1").html("Pause");
        jQuery("#growPlayPauseBtn1").fadeOut();
    }
    if ($(e.target).attr("id") == 'growPlayPauseBtn2') {
        /// alert('2');
        var title = "GROW Meeting 26 Aug 2020";
        AddListItem(title);
        videoClip2.play();
        jQuery("#growPlayPauseBtn2").html("Pause");
        jQuery("#growPlayPauseBtn2").fadeOut();
    }
   
}

function AddListItem(TitleField) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        batchCmd: "New",
        listName: "growVideoHits", //vidHit
        valuepairs: [
            ["Title", TitleField]
        ],
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            //alert("Data Saved! and Please check your List");
        }
    });
}
```

How I add content to the HTML:  I use the REST API get option to detect a new item loaded into the SharePoint folder.

```
getFilesFromFolder("/sites/dcsa/ep/epMainFilesBI/video").done(function(data){
```

Then I concatenate the items from the folder onto the HTML page with the below script:

```
$("#column1 ol").append('<li style="width:30%; height: auto; position: relative; left: 5%; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; float: left;" data-event-date="' + item.TimeCreated.split("T")[0] + '"><div class="btnImg" id="growPlayPauseBtn'+ i +'"  style="width: 285px; height: 225px; position: absolute; top: 20px; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; padding: 10px; color: white; background-color: rgba(43, 92, 171, .35); display: block;">Play Video</div><video width="100%" height="auto" controls onended="videoEnded1()" id="videoClip'+ i +'"><source src="' +  item.ServerRelativeUrl + '" type="audio/mpeg" >' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + " - "  + '<span style="color: red;">' + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0] + '</span>'  + '</video><span  style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;  float: left; clear: both;" "' + item.TimeCreated.split("T")[0] + '">' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")  + " - "  + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0]  + '</span></br><div class="vidViews" id="vidHit'+ i +'">Views: <span></span></div></li>');
```

Comment: i dont understant what part of your code detects when a new video is added, and the function which includes the new video in html code..could you precise?

Comment: I updated my question to show how I add the content to the HTML page.  In the script please notice the item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") part.  This call pulls the video from the SharePoint folder.

Comment: so you know you have a new video with the date of now (daily date), and the date of creation of video, so the most recent video has the more recent date ? and you rebuild the html each time , i mean completely with all names videos?

Comment: Do you know a better way of doing this video view concept.  Currently it works.  But when I add a new video, I have to physically go into the JavaScript and renumber my items.  When the video is add, video that was in the first position (zero index) in not in the second position (one index).  I have to change to JavaScript according to reflect this shift in numbering.  I'm thinking I can do this in a dynamic way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i have well understood your code, the new item are created in the `else part` so i suggest you to do a first loop to detect old videos from new videos and create html after:

```
getFilesFromFolder("/sites/dcsa/ep/epMainFiles/BI/video").done(function(data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {

        var spDate = new Date(item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0]) //example: '2015-10-30T05:00:00Z'
        var newTillDate = new Date();
        spDate.setDate(spDate.getDate() + 2);

        var newitems = [], olditems= [];
        if (spDate <= newTillDate) {
            olditems.push(item);
        } else {
            newitems.push(item);
        }

        var nbrolditems = olditems.length;
        for(let i = 0;i < nbrolditems; i++){
            let item = olditem[i];

            jQuery("#hiddenWrapper").fadeIn();

            $("#column1 ol").append('<li style="width:30%; height: auto; position: relative; left: 5%; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; float: left;" data-event-date="' + item.TimeCreated.split("T")[0] + '"><div class="btnImg" id="growPlayPauseBtn' + i + '"  style="width: 285px; height: 225px; position: absolute; top: 20px; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; padding: 10px; color: white; background-color: rgba(43, 92, 171, .35); display: block;">Play Video</div><video width="100%" height="auto" controls onended="videoEnded1()" id="videoClip' + i + '"><source src="' + item.ServerRelativeUrl + '" type="audio/mpeg" >' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + " - " + '<span style="color: red;">' + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0] + '</span>' + '</video><span  style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;  float: left; clear: both;" "' + item.TimeCreated.split("T")[0] + '">' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + " - " + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0] + '</span></br><div class="vidViews" id="vidHit' + i + '">Views: <span></span></div></li>');

            $("#column1 h3").html("Videos");
        } 
        
        for(let j = 0;j < newitems.length; j++){
            let item = olditem[j;
            let i = j + nbrolditems;
            
            jQuery("#hiddenWrapper").fadeIn();

            $("#column1 ol").append('<li style="width:30%; height: auto; position: relative; left: 5%; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; float: left;" data-event-date="' + item.TimeCreated.split("T")[0] + '"><div class="btnImg" id="growPlayPauseBtn' + i + '"  style="width: 285px; height: 225px; position: absolute; top: 20px; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; padding: 10px; color: white; background-color: rgba(43, 92, 171, .35); display: block;">Play Video</div><video width="100%" height="auto" controls onended="videoEnded1()" id="videoClip' + i + '"><source src="' + item.ServerRelativeUrl + '" type="audio/mpeg" >' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + " - " + '<span style="color: red;">' + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0] + '</span>' + '</video><span  style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;  float: left; clear: both;" "' + item.TimeCreated.split("T")[0] + '">' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + " - " + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0] + '</span></br><div class="vidViews" id="vidHit' + i + '">Views: <span></span></div></li>');

            $("#column1 h3").html('<img class="newArrow" style="width: 60px; position: relative; right: 5px; top: 0px;"src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Test Page/icons/arrow-with_new2.gif" alt="logo">Videos');
        }
    });
});
```

Another idea is to sort the list by date of creation of video....